# how to change api call destination based on user input?(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram

I have the following API call point:

```
iostCall = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=IOST&tsyms=USD,JPY,EUR"
```

I want to concatenate an input from my telegram user at (IOST).

this is what I have currently wrote but i have to hard code each call to the api.

```
def test (bot, update, args):
    params = {
        'fsym' : fsym
        }
    testCall = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price"
    testJson = requests.get(testCall, params=params)
    testOut = testJson
    update.message.reply_text(testOut)
```

and this is what sends the command to the telegram api. basically, my script waits till a user calls /test (inputs a coin name)... for example: /test btc

```
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("test", test, pass_args=True))
```

sends it to my user.

Comment: `currencies = input('enter your currencies (separated by space)').split()`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, pass a new parameter which will have the value. This way you can change the parameter every time, rather than hard coding. For example:

```
def iost(bot, update, fsym, tsym):
    params = {
      'fsym' : fsym,
      'tsyms' : tsym
    }

    iostCall = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price"
    iostCallJson = requests.get(iostCall, params=params).json()
    iostOut = iostCallJson 
    update.message.reply_text(iostOut)

iost(bot= bot, update= update, fsym='IOST', tsyms='USD,JPY,EUR')
```

Comment: my user defines fsym= with an input to the telegram chat.     return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
TypeError: test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fsym'
 is the error i get

Comment: @toBePythonNinja could you post your updated code as an edit?

Comment: I changed some things to make it into what i was going for much check up top. i will add a new edit

Comment: @toBePythonNinja is args the variable?

Comment: yes, in this case args changes with user input. def test is the function that is called when my user /test (then they place args here to resemble coins in the api info like  iost was an orgianl end point in the api) i would like my users input to edit this endpoint call.

Comment: Could you print args and check if is string or not? If it's the string input then you need to replace `'fsym' : fsym` with `'fsym': args`

Comment: say my user types /test eos. I want to replace iost with the "eos" argument that was given. tsyms can stay the same

Comment: tsym or each instance? TypeError: Object of type Response is not JSON serializable is what happens if i change it to 'fsym': args.

Comment: @toBePythonNinja I don't think I can help you any more since I don't have knowledge of telegram, and the purpose of your code. My answer was pretty much straight forward to what you asked, regarding how can it be made param driven. And I think I have answered your question.

Comment: will look deeper into what exactly your solution is doing and work it into my code. Thanks for all your help!---- this is the error im getting now.... i assume it has to do with the arg not properly going back into the json request